# not able to update file when condition is met

Tags: python, python-3.x

so there is a file , in which i need to update specific lines following conditions,i have added my code at bottom problem is i am able to print updated lines do not know to create a file with updated code

```
if two consecutive lines has CAR words 
at least any of consecutive lines should have '*' in it 
if above two condition is satisfied then 
put '*' two next two lines also ,make sure if a line already has '*' do not add '*' in it
```

findally ,update the text file

For example

PLEASE NOTE file contains hundreds of such instances ,need to correct all

filename4.txt

```
-------------
* CAR SDFSG FDSFDFDSF   
     CAR FDGDSGGF
bla bla
bla

 CAR SDdsfdfFSG FDSFDFDSF   
     CAR FdffdsDGDSGGF
bla 
bla
----------
expected updated file should be like this

* CAR SDFSG FDSFDFDSF   
*     CAR FDGDSGGF
*bla bla
*bla

 CAR SDdsfdfFSG FDSFDFDSF   
     CAR FdffdsDGDSGGF
bla 
bla
-------------------
```

here is my code

```
import re
with open("filename4.txt","r+") as file:
      lines = file.readlines()

      x=0

      if re.findall("CAR",lines[x]) and re.findall("CAR",lines[x+1]):
          if re.findall("\*",lines[x]) or re.findall("\*",lines[x+1]):
            if not re.findall("\*",lines[x]):
                lines[x] = "      * "+lines[x]
                print(lines[x])
            if not re.findall("\*",lines[x+1]):
                lines[x+1] = "      * "+lines[x+1]
                print(lines[x+1])
            if not re.findall("\*",lines[x+2]):
                lines[x+2] = "      * "+lines[x+2]
                print(lines[x+2])
            if not re.findall("\*",lines[x+3]):
                lines[x+3] = "      * "+lines[x+3]
                print(lines[x+3])
```

Comment: Is there a question or did you just want to tell us, that you wrote the code?

Comment: If you want people to review your code, Stack Overflow is not the site for that. Post on [codereviews.se] but check their posting guidelines first; they, too, want to know what sort of issues you are having.

Comment: i am not able to create update file , i have mentioned my effort only @Piinthesky

Comment: @Piinthesky hahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahaha yea we got trolled xD

Comment: i have updated  the question , thanks @tripleee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have multiple lines which go together, separated by a blank line, and then all the changes are done on this whole record. So, you need to break the file into records, first.

Once you do that, the rest becomes easy. Also notice the use of functions to handle different tasks, and make each part of the code responsible for one specific task (mostly).

```
# print one multi-line record
def output_record(lines):
    needs_prefix = is_condition_met(lines)
    for line in lines:
        if needs_prefix and '*' not in line:
            print ('*', line)
        else:
            print (line)
    print()

# determine if this record meets the condition for special handling
def is_condition_met(lines):
    if len(lines) >= 2:
        if 'CAR' in lines[0] and 'CAR' in lines[1]:
            if '*' in lines[0] or '*' in lines[1]:
                return True
    return False

# because I didn't want to do file IO in this example
all_lines = [
    '* CAR SDFSG FDSFDFDSF   ',
    '    CAR FDGDSGGF',
    'bla bla',
    'bla',
    '',
    '    CAR SDdsfdfFSG FDSFDFDSF   ',
    '        CAR FdffdsDGDSGGF',
    'bla ',
    'bla'
]

# parse the whole file into multi-line records
lines_this_record = []
for line in all_lines:
    if line:
        lines_this_record.append(line)
    else:
        output_record(lines_this_record)
        lines_this_record = []

# last record may still need to be printed, 
# if we look for newlines, but there was no blank line at the end of file
if lines_this_record:
    output_record(lines_this_record)
```

Comment: Also, I didn't use regex because it seemed like overkill. You just needed to find a string literal, and python's "in" operator on a string handles that. If you need regex because there is more to it in the real code, then go ahead.

Comment: Special note - my record parsing would remove extra newlines. If you don't want that to happen, then append them to the record, and fix output_record to handle blank lines correctly.

Comment: thank you , i never thought in itself is capable of doing it

Comment: one problem m  i am facing is that when file size is huge like 60000 lines , list can hold all of it . what could possible solution for it

Comment: I never intended the whole file to be in the list -- that was just so I could post a self-contained example. Replace that list with calls to readline. You only need the lines in one record until you print out the record, then you can forget them forever (assuming stdout is being piped to a file).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you kenney , your answer helps me a lot 
here is alternative version , i am using findall more frequently

```
import re


def comment(a,b):
#  print("comment on",a,"condn",b)
  if b == 1:
    list[a+1] = "      * " +    list[a+1]
    list[a+2] = "      * " +    list[a+2]
    list[a+3] = "      * " +    list[a+3]
  if b == 2:
    list[a+2] = "      * " +    list[a+2]
    list[a+3] = "      * " +    list[a+3
                                     ]
    list[a] = "      * "   +    list[a]
  if b == 3:
    print(a)
    list[a+2] = "      * " +    list[a+2]
    list[a+3] = "      * " +    list[a+3]


with open("filename4.txt","r+") as file:
   lines = file.readlines()
   list = lines[:]
   x=0
   for line in lines:
      if re.findall("CAR",lines[x]) and re.findall("CAR",lines[x+1]):
          if re.findall("\*",lines[x]) or re.findall("\*",lines[x+1]):
            if re.findall("\*",lines[x]):
              if not re.findall("\*",lines[x+1]):
                comment(x,1)
            if not re.findall("\*",lines[x]):
              if re.findall("\*",lines[x+1]):
                comment(x,2)

            if re.findall("\*",lines[x]):
              if re.findall("\*",lines[x+1]):
                comment(x,3)


      x=x+1  


with open('path.txt', 'w') as file_handler:
    for item in list:
        file_handler.write("{}".format(item))
```